# Comparing and remove files

Tags: shell-script, file-comparison

In linux, i have one file which having only file names inside( 60 file names only,no other contents),

*file60.txt*

```
  foo
  foo123
  ...
  bar
```

and another file with 63 file names, mostly the same, but 3 more.

*file63.txt*

```
  foo
  foo123
  ...
  hello
  bar
  world
  baz
```

How to compare the content of  `file60.txt` with the content of `file63.txt` ?

Comment: Compare it in what way? Do you want the common lines? Those in file60 that aren't in file63? Those in file63 that aren't in file60? All of the above? And what should be "removed"? Please [edit] your question and show us your desired output.

Comment: how about viewing them with `gvimdiff`  or `tkdiff`??

Answer (score 1):

if file are sorted

```
comm -13 file60.txt file63.txt
```

if file are unsorted

```
comm -13 <(sort file60.txt) <(sort file63.txt)
```

to remove

```
rm $(comm -13 <(sort file60.txt) <(sort file63.txt))
```